# How to add a class to vertical tabs created using Form API?

Tags: theming, forms

Form API element `vertical_tabs` does not have `#attributes` property.

I have two kinds of tabs. The first one is language dependent. The second one has language independent values, just shows a preview in the selected template. I want them to be visibly different on first glance.

How can I mark them, possibly without adding dummy containers that makes the form tree more complicated than form logic requires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the wrapper container, another option may be to override the theme function in template.php:

[theme_vertical_tabs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_vertical_tabs/7)

You could add some logic and classes there.

e.g:

```
$output .= '<div class="vertical-tabs-panes my-class">' . $element['#children'] . '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right vartical tabs don't have #attributes element.
But you can:

1) place vertical tabs in `#container` element with class. There you can use `#attributes`

2) you can add `#prefix`, `#suffix` into tabs:

```
$tabs['#prefix'] = '<div class="my-class">';

$tabs['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```